# Replace 'middle' frequencies with averaged frequency values

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this type of data, with `f`requency data and `position` data grouped by `rowid`:

```
df
   rowid    word   f position
1      2       i 700        1
2      2      'm 600        2
3      2    fine   1        3
4      3     how 400        1
5      3      's 500        2
6      3     the 700        3
7      3 weather  20        4
8      4      it 390        1
9      4      's 500        2
10     4  really 177        3
11     4    very 200        4
12     4    cold  35        5
13     5       i 700        1
14     5    love 199        2
15     5     you 400        3
```

The task I'm facing seems simple: in those `rowid`s where there are more than 3 `positions`, I need to replace the `f`requencies of all middle `position`s with their average. The following approach works but seems over-convoluted, so I'm almost certain there will be a more straightforward `dplyr`way to get the desired output:

```
df %>%
  group_by(rowid) %>%
  # filter for 'middle' positions:
  filter(position != first(position) & position != last(position)) %>%
  # summarise:
  summarize(across(position),
            # create average frequency:
            f_middle_position = mean(f, na.rm = TRUE),
            # concatenate words:
            word = str_c(word, collapse = " ")
            ) %>%
  filter(!duplicated(f_middle_position)) %>%
  # join with df:
  left_join(df, ., by = c("rowid", "position")) %>%
  # remove rows other than #1,#2, and last:
  group_by(rowid) %>%
  # create row count:
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
  # filter first, second, and last row per group:
  filter(rn %in% c(1, 2, last(rn))) %>%
  # transfer frequencies for middle positions:
  mutate(f = ifelse(is.na(f_middle_position), f, f_middle_position)) %>%
  # make more changes:
  mutate(
    # change position labels:
    position = ifelse(position == first(position), 1,
                           ifelse(position == last(position), 2, 1.5)),
    # update word:
    word = ifelse(is.na(word.y), word.x, word.y)
         ) %>%
  # remove obsolete variables:
  select(-c(f_middle_position, word.y, word.x,rn))
 A tibble: 12 × 4
# Groups:   rowid [4]
   rowid     f position word          
   <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>         
 1     2  700       1   i             
 2     2  600       1.5 'm            
 3     2    1       2   fine          
 4     3  400       1   how           
 5     3  600       1.5 's the        
 6     3   20       2   weather       
 7     4  390       1   it            
 8     4  292.      1.5 's really very
 9     4   35       2   cold          
10     5  700       1   i             
11     5  199       1.5 love          
12     5  400       2   you
```

How can this result be obtained in a more concise way in `dplyr` and, preferably **without** the `left_join`, which causes problems with my actual data?

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  rowid = c(2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5),
  word = c("i","'m","fine",
           "how","'s","the","weather",
           "it","'s","really", "very","cold",
           "i","love","you"),
  f = c(700,600,1,
        400,500,700,20,
        390,500,177,200,35,
        700,199,400),
  position = c(1,2,3,
               1,2,3,4,
               1,2,3,4,5,
               1,2,3)
)
```

Comment: like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75055207/problem-with-left-join-join-columns-must-be-present/75055512#75055512

Comment: No, looking for a `dplyr` solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a group variable `pos` that marks the first row with `1`, the middle with `1.5`, and the last with `2`. Then group the data by `rowid` and `pos` and apply `mean()` and `paste()` on `f` and `word` respectively.

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(rowid) %>% 
  mutate(pos = case_when(position == 1 ~ 1, position == n() ~ 2, TRUE ~ 1.5)) %>%
  group_by(rowid, pos) %>%
  summarise(f = mean(f), word = paste(word, collapse = ' '), .groups = 'drop')

# # A tibble: 12 × 4
#    rowid   pos     f word          
#    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>         
#  1     2   1    700  i             
#  2     2   1.5  600  'm            
#  3     2   2      1  fine          
#  4     3   1    400  how           
#  5     3   1.5  600  's the        
#  6     3   2     20  weather       
#  7     4   1    390  it            
#  8     4   1.5  292. 's really very
#  9     4   2     35  cold          
# 10     5   1    700  i             
# 11     5   1.5  199  love          
# 12     5   2    400  you
```

Comment: Wow - really beautiful, so simple and clear